# python converting special characters ↓ and ↑ to â and á when reading excel file

Tags: python, dataframe, symbols

I am reading excel file that contains symbols ↓ and ↑ into dataframe and they're converted to string â and á.

I am currently replacing them back to arrows using df.replace({'â' : '↓', 'á' : '↑'}).

Was wondering if there is a dataframe workaround to keep the arrow symbols when reading in excel?

Comment: which version of python are you using ?

Comment: It's likely a character encoding mismatch from the Excel (CSV?) file to the python script. The most straightforward way to resolve is to save the file from Excel in UTF-8 or convert it elsewhere.

Comment: @SimonDelecourt I'm on 3.7